# React Native Admob Google Mobile Ads not working. I am getting blank page when I click on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, admob

The App is working fine even when I disconnect the internet, but when I disconnect the internet app pages are not working where I implemented google ads. the app pages show blank pages not even load the app page data. I know ads will not appear when I disconnect the internet but the problem is I am also not getting the page data, it shows blank page. how can I solve this issue? thank you in advance for your support.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Button, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { InterstitialAd, AdEventType, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.INTERSTITIAL : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712';
const interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
  keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
});

const Test = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = interstitial.addAdEventListener(AdEventType.LOADED, () => {
      setLoaded(true);
      interstitial.show()
    });
    interstitial.load();
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello World</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
export default Test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have this in your code

```
if (!loaded) {
  return null;
}
```

It returns `null` when your ad is not loaded so it shows blank screen remove that and you'll have your screen